# Calculate earlier and later times, then compare with a given time

Tags: android

I need to calculate if a certain time is between 30 minutes earlier and 20 minutes later than the current time.

Any idea how to do this?

The problem is when the time is 23:50h, for example. So I can't do a simple comparison since 23 is greater than 00. But I must consider it smaller since it's another day.

**Example:**

Now is 23:45. Testing 23:50.

23:45 - 30 minutes = 23:15.

23:45 + 20 minutes = 00:05.

Is 23:50 between 23:15 and 00:05?

**Another example:**

Now is 00:05. Testing 00:15.

00:05 - 30 minutes = 23:35.

00:05 + 20 minutes = 00:25.

Is 00:15 between 23:35 and 00:25?

--

minSdkVersion is **22**, and this further limits the available solutions.

Comment: Hello. In that case it's "23.50", is "00.10" 20 mins later or hours before it? Just to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to go is :

Compare Hours separately from minutes.

Or also you can take the Hours, multiply them for 60 and then add the returning value to the minutes amount, that will end up with a "only minute" calculation between the 2 times. You can make whatever operation you need.

The only case you should calculate is that one you are in a different day, but that dipends and what you are trying to accomplish!

CODE IN JAVA (OLD VERSION):

```
    public class Main 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            //Input TIME
            String date  = "23.45";
        
            //Calculating the TIME in MINUTES ONLY
            int date_m = normalizeTime(date);
        
            //CALCULATE MAX AND MIN TIMES
            int max = date_m+20;
            int min = date_m-30;
        
            /*
        
                Working like that we don't
                need to worry about the day Before or After
        
            */
       
            //JUST DEBUG PRINTS TO SHOW YOU THAT
            System.out.println("MAX TIME : "+max);
            System.out.println("MIN TIME : "+min);
        
            //The TIME that has to be tested
            String testDate = "23.50";
       
            //Calculating the TIME in MINUTES ONLY
            int testDate_m = normalizeTime(testDate);
       
            //JUST A DEBUG PRINT TO SHOW YOU THE TESTED TIME
            System.out.println("TESTED TIME : "+testDate_m);
       
            /*
                If the testDate_m is Between the MAX and MIN values it's 
                TRUE else it's FALSE
                If needed you can adjust with >= or <=
                That doesn't matter for the logic.
            */
            if(testDate_m<max && testDate_m>min)
                 System.out.println("IT IS BETWEEN!");
            else
                System.out.println("IT ISN'T BETWEEN!");
            
            //DONE!
        }
    
    /*
        Just a Method to clean up the code:
        Basically it will Split the string in HOURS and MINUTES
        and it will make a simple operation of : Hour*60(Transforming it to minutes) + minutes
        
        The return is an INT that represent the inserted TIME as a MINUTE ONLY TIME.
        
        If the returned number is more than 24*60 it's the Day Next (don't need to worry about that)
        If the returned number is less than 0 it's the Previous Day (don't need to worry about that)
    */
    private static int normalizeTime(String time)
    {
        int h = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0,2));
        int m = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3,5));
        return h*60+m;
    } 
}
```

CODE IN JAVA (NEW VERSION) :

```
public class Main 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            boolean inTime = true;
            //Input TIME
            String date  = "23.50";
        
            //Calculating the TIME in MINUTES ONLY
            int date_m = normalizeTime(date);
        
            //CALCULATE MAX AND MIN TIMES
            int max = date_m+20;
            int min = date_m-30;
            int prevMin = max;
            int nextMax = min;
            
            if(min<0)
            {
                prevMin = 24*60+min;
                nextMax = 24*60+max;
            }
            else if(max>24*60)
            {
                prevMin = min-24*60;
                nextMax = max-24*60;
            }
        
            /*
        
                Working like that we don't
                need to worry about the day Before or After
        
            */
       
            //JUST DEBUG PRINTS TO SHOW YOU THAT
            
            System.out.println("Between :"+min+" and "+max);
            System.out.println("OR");
            System.out.println("Between : "+prevMin+" and "+nextMax);
            
            //The TIME that has to be tested
            String testDate = "00.05";
       
            //Calculating the TIME in MINUTES ONLY
            int testDate_m = normalizeTime(testDate);
       
            //JUST A DEBUG PRINT TO SHOW YOU THE TESTED TIME
            System.out.println("TESTED TIME : "+testDate_m);
       
            /*
                If the testDate_m is Between the MAX and MIN values it's 
                TRUE else it's FALSE
                If needed you can adjust with >= or <=
                That doesn't matter for the logic.
            */
            
            if((testDate_m<max && testDate_m>min) || (testDate_m<nextMax && testDate_m>prevMin))
                 System.out.println("IT IS BETWEEN!");
            else
                System.out.println("IT ISN'T BETWEEN!");
            
            //DONE!
        }
    
    /*
        Just a Method to clean up the code:
        Basically it will Split the string in HOURS and MINUTES
        and it will make a simple operation of : Hour*60(Transforming it to minutes) + minutes
        
        The return is an INT that represent the inserted TIME as a MINUTE ONLY TIME.
        
        If the returned number is more than 24*60 it's the Day Next (don't need to worry about that)
        If the returned number is less than 0 it's the Previous Day (don't need to worry about that)
    */
    private static int normalizeTime(String time)
    {
        int h = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0,2));
        int m = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3,5));
        return h*60+m;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried to explain my question better. I need to consider the different days

Comment: Can you please elaborate your suggestion better? I've tried everything, using Calendar, Date... but nothing worked. I think your suggestion will be the best solution.

Comment: I coded a working example in Java you can execute even on an Online Compiler to Test if it is what you are looking for, feel free to tell me if there is something else you need! I used this : [Java Online Compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler)

Comment: Test with date = "00.01"; It's going to go wrong. The problem is much more complicated than it looks.

Comment: What is going wrong with it? The fact is that : If you put 00.01 and the time is 23.50 I assume that 23.50 is the current day, not the previous one. If you want your program to assume 23.50 is the previous you didn't say that you have also a "Date" or something else to look for.

Or maybe are you just saying that doesn't matter if it's 23.50 it's obviously the day before because your program is gonna deal only with "in-range" times?

Comment: Added new Version of the code to adapt to your request as I intended it. Test It!

Comment: Edited once again. I think I touched every cases now. If it's not enaugh please explain what you are trying to accomplish better!

Comment: Great! Congratulations on the solution. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to work with timestamps.

```
long time = new Date().getTime();
long thiry_earlier = time - minutes_to_ms(30);
long twenty_later = time + minutes_to_ms(20);

if(compare < twenty_later && compare > thirty_earlier) {
//do whatever
}

long minutes_to_ms(long minutes) {
  return minutes*60*1000;
}
```

There's some nicer conversion functions you can use nowdays I'm just too lazy to look them up.  But working with raw timestamps makes everything easier for comparisons.

Comment: I'm having trouble testing when the time is close to overnight. Do you have any suggestions?